# Is $f(t)=\frac{1}{(t+2)(t-1)}$ continuous at $x = 1$ if $t =\frac{1}{(x-1)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

My book$^*$ only mentions the points of discontinuity as $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x= 2$.

I think $x= 1$ is also a point of discontinuity as $t$ is not defined for $x = 1$. But upon substitution and simplification $x$ the function is continuous at $x=1$. But, this approach to determining continuity seems to be wrong.
For if $g(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$, we do not claim that the function is continuous at $x=4$ even though $g(x)$ simplifies to $(x+2)$. So, why does my book claim that $f(t)$ is continuous at $x=1$? What am I not seeing?

$^*$Arihant NCERT Exemplar Problems-Solutions Class XII Mathematics Book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But upon substitution and simplification x the function is continuous at x=1.
>
> But, this approach to determining continuity seems to be wrong.

It is.   Don't simplify it.

---

Rather, we have *by substitution alone* that the expression of $f(1/(x-1))$ is: $$\dfrac{1}{(\tfrac 1{x-1}+2)(\tfrac 1{x-1}-1)}$$

Since the numerator is constant, we need only look at the denominator to find discontinuities.

This expression is discontinuous when the *denominator vanishes*; and that is when $\tfrac 1{x-1}+2=0$ or $\tfrac{1}{x-1}-1=0$.   Thus we claim $x=1/2$ and $x=2$ as discontinuity points.

The expression is *not* regarded as discontinuous when the *denominator explodes* (at $x=1$), because at that point we safely evaluate the whole expression as zero.

Comment: Please stop pushing the idea that holes in a (not given domain) are discontinuities. That is just wrong.

Comment: @LukasBetz since, $x=1$ simply doesn't belong to the domain of the function and therefore, the question of discontinuity at $x=1$ does not arise?

Comment: @SatishChandraChitrapu Yes. The domain should actually be given rather than inferred. But if you take the domain of all reals without the zeros of any denominator of fractions in the expression then yes, it doesn't even make sense to talk about continuity in points where the function is not defined.